# Como evitar usar SetTimeOut en esta llamada a la API de Google?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, nextjs

> EDIT: La pregunta inicialmente era evitar un error en consola, el mismo ya fue evitado mediante la configuracion de Next.JS gracias al comentario de Pablo. Ahora busco otra respuesta, que sea como hacer que mi codigo funcione, sin usar setTimeout, es por ello que cambio el titulo de la misma.

Estoy obteniendo lugares cercanos a un punto con la API de Google maps.

En un momento me esta saliendo un error (indicado acá abajo) pero el código continua su ejecución y finalmente me devuelve el resultado esperado. (asi es, todo me funciona bien, solo que me aparece ese error en la consola de node, y quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal para que aparezca, para evitarlo.)

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/google/places/33.807501/-78.70039, this may result in stalled requests.

El código empieza por la ultima línea del `try` cuando hago `fetchNearbyPlaces();` , entonces se ejecuta dicha funcion, la cual es recursiva.

`fetchNearbyPlaces` inicialmente no recibe ningun parametro, entonces hago la llamada normal. Si el resultado de esta llamada trae un `next_page_token`, indica que puedo traer más resultados.

Entonces, en este caso, vuelvo a llamar a `fetchNearbyPlaces` pero esta vez pasandole un parametro...

**(EN ESTE MOMENTO ES CUANDO ME SALE EL ERROR)**

... hasta que en un momento el resultado ya no devuelve un `next_page_token`, en ese momento entra al `else`, limpio los resultados, llamo a `fetchNearbyBeaches` para encontrar playas cercanas, y finalmente desde esta función retorno todo el resultado.

Agregué VARIOS `console.log` para ver si puedo identificar en que momento aparece el error, (dejo los console en el codigo) y lo que veo por consola es lo siguiente:

```
- llamamos a fetchnearbyplaces
- fetchNearbyPlaces indica que hay mas resultados, vuelvo a llamar
- ERROR: API resolved without sending a response for /api/google/places/33.807501/-78.70039, this may result in stalled requests.
- llamamos a fetchnearbyplaces
- fetchNearbyPlaces indica que hay mas resultados, vuelvo a llamar
- llamamos a fetchnearbyplaces
- Ya no hay mas resultados, limpio el resultado y llamo a fetchNearbyBeaches
- Desde fetchNearbyBeaches. Misma logica que para fecthNearbyPlaces
- Desde fetchNearbyBeaches. Misma logica que para fecthNearbyPlaces
- Finalmente devuelvo el resultado de la llamada
```

Este es mi código:

```
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude}%2C${longitude}&radius=${radius}&key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`;

  const beachesUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude}%2C${longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=natural_feature&key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`;

  try {
    let results = [];
    let beaches = [];
    const fetchNearbyBeaches = async (urlWithToken = null) => {
      console.log("Desde fetchNearbyBeaches. Misma logica que para fecthNearbyPlaces");
      await axios.get(urlWithToken ? urlWithToken : beachesUrl).then(data => {
        beaches = [...beaches, ...data.data.results];
        if (data?.data?.next_page_token) {
          const newUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&pagetoken=${data.data.next_page_token}`;

          setTimeout(() => {
            fetchNearbyBeaches(newUrl);
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          console.log("Finalmente devuelvo el resultado de la llamada");
          beaches.length > 5 && beaches.splice(5);
          results.length > 5 && results.splice(5);

          const finalResults = [...beaches, ...results];

          finalResults.length > 10 && finalResults.splice(10);
          return res.status(200).json({
            data: {
              results: finalResults,
            },
            success: true,
          });
        }
      });
    };

    const fetchNearbyPlaces = async (urlWithToken = null) => {
      console.log("llamamos a fetchnearbyplaces");
      await axios.get(urlWithToken ? urlWithToken : url).then(data => {
        results = [...results, ...data.data.results];
        if (data?.data?.next_page_token) {
          const newUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${process.env.CW_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&pagetoken=${data.data.next_page_token}`;
          console.log("fetchNearbyPlaces indica que hay mas resultados, vuelvo a llamar");
          setTimeout(() => {
            fetchNearbyPlaces(newUrl);
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          console.log("Ya no hay mas resultados, limpio el resultado y llamo a fetchNearbyBeaches");

          const dirtyResultsWithDuplicates = [];
          results.map(result => {
            return types.map(type => {
              if (checkFunc(result.types, type) && !result.types.includes("lodging")) {
                dirtyResultsWithDuplicates.push(result);
              }
            });
          });

          const set = new Set(dirtyResultsWithDuplicates);
          const filtered = Array.from(set);

          results = filtered.length > 10 ? filtered.splice(10) : filtered;
          
          fetchNearbyBeaches();
        }
      });
    };

   fetchNearbyPlaces();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message,
      statusCode: 500,
    });
  }
```

EDIT:

Esta funcion para hacer fetch a la api de google se ejecuta desde un componente, a traves de `useSWR`

```
 const nearbyPlacesURL = resortDetails?.geoCoordinates?.lat && resortDetails?.geoCoordinates?.lon ? `/api/google/places/${resortDetails?.geoCoordinates?.lat}/${resortDetails?.geoCoordinates?.lon}/` : null;

  if (nearbyPlacesURL) {
    dataFetcher = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data?.data?.results);
  }

  const {
    data: nearbyPlaces,
  } = useSWR(nearbyPlacesURL, dataFetcher, {
    revalidateIfStale: false,
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  });
```

Comment: Ese código que muestras ahi... se ejecuta dentro de una ruta de express? o cuando se ejecuta? podrías aclarar o agregar esa parte del código?

Comment: Hola @Pipe, este codigo se ejecuta en un componente de ruta de ``next.js``  a traves de ``useSWR``. Agregue el bloque al final de mi pregunta y edité los tags

Comment: No se mucho de next.js... pero tengo entendido que ese error sale cuando se termina una ejecucion sin haber retornado una respuesta... para este caso creo que la solución podría estar en poner un `await`. Cambia la linea antes del catch por `await fetchNearbyPlaces();`.

Comment: @Pipe vos te referis a la llamada inmediatamente antes del catch? Originalmente tenia un ``await`` y asi subi la pregunta. Probando, elimine este await y veo que funciona igual, por lo que lo elimine de la pregunta tambien

Comment: Creo que el problema debe estar entonces en el `timeout`, porque esto hace que la ejecución continue y por eso sale antes de obtener todos los datos. Yo creo que la solución estaría en plantar toda esa funcion como un `Promise`... y solo llamar a resolve cuando ya tengas todos los resultados

Comment: porque debes esperar 2000ms para esos llamados?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#PlaceSearchPaging la documentacion dice que hay un retraso, no recuerdo exactamente donde lei que ese retraso es 2 segundos

Comment: @Pipe tiene sentido lo de envolver todo en un Promise, ahora no estoy en la compu pero cuando vuelva lo intento. Gracias!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139532/discussion-between-pipe-and-agustin-g).

Comment: Agregando ese objeto ```export config.api.externalResolver: true```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu código, el problema es el siguiente:

- Se recibe una request
- Tu servidor encuentra la función a ejecutar y realiza la llamada a dicha función.
- La llamada termina, pero como el objeto `res` no ha sido usado para dar una respuesta (se ha delegado la conclusión con un timeout), aparece el warning: se ha terminado de procesar en el hilo asociado a la request pero no se ha mandado todavía una respuesta (seguramente axios hace una comprobación del estado del objeto `res`).

No me queda muy claro por qué usas un timeout y esperas dos segundos en lugar de simplemente llamar a la función, pero ése es el motivo del aviso. Puedes ignorarlo (o desactivarlo con el flag `externalResolver = true`, como dice [la documentación](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers).

##### Actualización:

He estado mirando la documentación de Google Maps y he encontrado lo siguiente:

> Hay un retraso de unos segundos entre el momento en que se emite una
> `next_page_token` y el momento en que estará disponible. Si solicitas
> la página siguiente antes de que esté disponible, se mostrará una
> respuesta `INVALID_REQUEST`.

Esto explica que necesites retrasar la petición, pero hay una nota final explicando cómo esperan que uses la interfaz (las negritas son mías):

> **Nota**: El uso correcto de next_page_token consiste en solicitar la página siguiente de resultados **solo cuando el usuario lo solicita**. Te
> recomendamos que implementes la paginación real (que muestre 20
> resultados a la vez) o que agregues lugares adicionales en la parte
> inferior de la página de resultados una vez que el usuario se desplace
> hasta el final.

Realmente lo que se espera es que no la tengas automatizada: la forma de evitar usar `setTimeout` es no ser tan *ansioso* a la hora de obtener la información y sólo mostrar 20 entradas. Si el usuario quiere ver más, entonces se pide las siguientes 20 entradas.

Comment: Buen dia, si yo no ejecuto el setTimeOut no obtengo mas resultados, solo los de la primer llamada. Aunque use una función asíncrona dentro del then y un await en lugar el setTimeout. Hay delay aclarado en la documentacion, pero no funciona con async-await. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby

Comment: Por otro lado, la solucion que me das es la que estoy buscando. Agregando ese objeto ``export config.api.externalResolver: true`` se solucionó el problema. Muchisimas gracias! En una hora me deja asignarte la recompensa, saludos

Comment: He añadido cierta información sobre el uso del API, no sé si es lo que estás buscando

Comment: Te agradezco, eso mismo habia leido yo y por requerimientos tengo que obtener (de ser posible) 60 resultados para places, 60 para beaches, todo para finalmente terminar filtrando 10 resultados xD pero el que paga decide jaja. Gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo.